# How many principal components should I choose for PCA?

Tags: machine-learning, nlp, pca, svd

I have a dataframe with few categorical and numerical features. To that I've concatenated my BoW(CountVectorizer) of text column which resulted in more than 56,000 features. So I'm considering to do PCA for reducing number of features.

I think choosing correct number of principal components is crucial here but I'm confused on how many `n_components` to consider here?

Comment: Great question!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can plot a graph with the top k components and the variance of the k components.Choose k based on the variance contained in those components.95% or above would be ideal.

Comment: Yoshitha,  I'm doing a two class classification task and I'm training my model using KNN. The time complexity of KNN is really high for high dimensional data. For 95% variance I may have to choose more number of components thereby increasing dimensions. Is it mandatory to select 95% for every scenario ?

Comment: It is not needed that you have 95%. Check the graph and you can select the k based on the steep of the curve. If there is sudden drop in the variance somewhere, choose k just before the sudden drop. On top of it, visualise the data and make sure that you capture enough information from data with the k components.

Comment: can you check my variance plot. This is the [image](https://imgur.com/zvqM4RW). What do you suggest here? How many components should I choose?

Comment: It seems like you have to take number of components atleast 500.

Comment: I was also thinking the same. After 500 components increase in variance is less. I'll experiment and see. Thank you :)

Comment: I did the same with cumulative explained variance and take a 95% , but when plot the point in a scatter, why we use often the first 2 components? Ad example, if use 500 components, why when plot in scatter use just ax.scatter(X_PCA[:,0], X_PCA[:,1] )  @YoshithaPenaganti